# Why is there a thin red line showing as a border in Georgia in Google Earth?

Tags: geopolitics, borders, republic-of-georgia, caucasus

Why is there a thin red line showing as a border in Georgia in Google Earth?

[image]

Comment: You're looking at the South Ossetia country which is disputed between Georgia and Russia.

Comment: Google maps generally does stuff like this for disputed territories. Crimea is another famous example.

Comment: @Bregalad It's not disputed between Georgia and Russia.  It's disputed between Georgia and South Ossetia, which has declared independence, which Russia recognises but Georgia does not.  Russia does not claim sovereignty over South Ossetia.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, that is South Ossetia. Below is an image from Wikipedia of a map:

[image]

Basically, South Ossetia declared independence from the Georgian Soviet Socialist Republic (known as Georgia today) in 1991.

Currently, only 4 UN member states recognise South Ossetia, namely Russia, Nicaragua, Venezuela and Nauru.

Comment: And Kosovo has 115 recognitions. The only difference being that the independence of Kosovo is backed by the U.S.

Comment: @dan-klasson : the US is only 1 of the 111 differences...

Comment: @Evargalo Not exactly — Nauru recognises both, so there are 112 countries that recognise Kosovo but not South Ossetia.